# How to get all objects with parameters of other tables in NHibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have two classes:

```
public class Catalog
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Article>? Articles { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Catalog>? SubCatalogs { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Article
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual string Text { get; set; }
    public virtual Catalog? Catalog { get; set; }
}
```

I write this mappings:

```
public class CatalogMap : ClassMap<Catalog>
{
    public CatalogMap()
    {
        Table("Catalogs"); // Указываем имя таблицы в базе данных

        Id(x => x.Id); // Указываем, что поле Id является первичным ключом

        Map(x => x.Name); // Маппинг свойства Name как обычное поле в базе данных

        HasMany(x => x.Articles) // Определяем отношение один-ко-многим с сущностью Article
            .KeyNullable()
            .Cascade.All() // Указываем каскадирование операций
            .Inverse() // Указываем, что связь управляется сущностью Article
            .KeyColumn("CatalogId"); // Указываем имя внешнего ключа в таблице Articles

        HasMany(x => x.SubCatalogs) // Определяем отношение один-ко-многим с сущностью Catalog
            .KeyNullable()
            .Cascade.All() // Указываем каскадирование операций
            .Inverse() // Указываем, что связь управляется сущностью Catalog
            .KeyColumn("ParentCatalogId"); // Указываем имя внешнего ключа в таблице Catalogs
    }
}
```

and

```
public class ArticleMap : ClassMap<Article>
{
    public ArticleMap()
    {
        Table("Articles"); // Указываем имя таблицы в базе данных

        Id(x => x.Id); // Указываем, что поле Id является первичным ключом

        Map(x => x.Title); // Маппинг свойства Title как обычное поле в базе данных
        Map(x => x.Text); // Маппинг свойства Text как обычное поле в базе данных

        References(x => x.Catalog) // Определяем отношение многие-к-одному с сущностью Catalog
            .Column("CatalogId") // Указываем имя внешнего ключа в таблице Articles
            .Nullable()
            .Cascade.All(); // Указываем каскадирование операций
    }
}
```

I need to get all Catalogs including all Articles and SubCatalogs. I have already tried many options, but unfortunately nothing helped. Here is my code for creating a Catalog with the specified Articles and SubCatalogs:

```
var session = _sessionFactory.OpenSession();


using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    var cat = new Catalog
    {
        Name = "New Catalog"
    };

    var article1 = new Article
    {
        Title = "Article 1",
        Text = "Text 1",
        Catalog = cat
    };
    var article2 = new Article
    {
        Title = "Article 2",
        Text = "Text 2",
        Catalog = cat
    };

    var subCatalog1 = new Catalog
    {
        Name = "Sub Catalog 1"
    };
    var subCatalog2 = new Catalog
    {
        Name = "Sub Catalog 2"
    };
    
    cat.Articles = new List<Article> { article1, article2 };
    cat.SubCatalogs = new List<Catalog> { subCatalog1, subCatalog2 };

    session.Save(cat);

    transaction.Commit();
}
```

And here is my code to get all Catalogs:

```
var session = _sessionFactory.OpenSession();

using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    var catalogs = session.QueryOver<Catalog>()
        .Fetch(x => x.Articles).Eager
        .Fetch(x => x.SubCatalogs).Eager
        .List();

    var res = catalogs.ToList();

    return res;
}
```

I tried writing a query in SQL form, but that didn't work either. Every time I get a different Exception.